# How to pass outside parameter to CKEditor plugin

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I'm working on a plugin(application specific), that would allow to select an image from select box(`size=5`) and during the `onChange` event would show preview aside.

[image]

I have a set of urls, that lead to different images with small size. Issue here is, that plugin is an enclosed part of the code, where list of images is outside of it and is created by current action(not static).

Any way to pass it into plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time, but plugin was created.

Due to some fresh issues in `Chrome` it was not possible to say, wether the plugin and CKEditor add some strange behaviour or is it `Chrome`, but with testing in FF it was confirmed to be issue of Chrome(talking about selects `size` attribute).

Nevertheless, the issue with passing images for select was quite simple. I'm not sure whether it is the best way or not, but I was able to do it through `CKEDITOR.config.*`. More specifically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    CKEDITOR.config.pddimages_set = {{ images }};

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
});
</script>
```

Even more specifically `{{ images }}` is a `json_encode`d array. And that data was available to me in my plugin.

Hope that will help others who may come in contact with same question.